# How do I measure the distance from an object to fit it in the screen?

Tags: focal-length, calculations, subject-distance

I'm curious if there is any math formula for this.

Let's take a **close-up of a human face** for instance, given the **human face is about 20cm/8 inches**, how do I choose the **right focal length and from what distance a camera with a APS-C sensor should be** so that it fits in the top and the bottom of the frame with the whole face?

I just want to know how to mathematically calculate this. It doesn't matter the effects or distortions caused by a telephoto or a wide-angle lens.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is just Field of View, see http://www.scantips.com/lights/fieldofview.html

For a calculator, and if you know trig tangent, the diagram at page bottom will explain how.